# "webpack-dev-server" command not found - Docker with Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, webpack, docker-compose, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm currently working on "dockerizing" a Rails 6 app with MySQL as backend/admin-panel with an Angular 8 app as frontend for users. I tried to run both containers with docker-compose and the frontend works perfectly but the backend has a problem. The webpack server somehow cannot be started. It always tells me that the "webpack-dev-server" cannot be found and then exits. This is odd because I let the same setup run on a Linux/Ubuntu system and it works fine but on Mac the Webpacker fails.

This is my setup:

- OS Catalina: 10.15.1
- Node: 10.12.0
- Ruby: 2.5.5

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ruby:2.5.5

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - && \
    curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -qq -y \
        build-essential nodejs yarn libpq-dev \
    && mkdir -p /app \
    && apt-get clean autoclean \
    && apt-get autoremove -y

WORKDIR /tmp
COPY Gemfile* /tmp/
RUN bundle install

COPY package* /tmp/
COPY yarn* /tmp/
RUN yarn install

ADD scripts/entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 3000

# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
      - ./backend/scripts:/scripts
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    dns: # Needed for making request outside the container
      - 1.1.1.1
    command: ["/scripts/wait-for-it.sh", "db:3306", "--", "/scripts/wait-for-it.sh", "webpacker:3035", "--", "/scripts/start_rails.sh"]
    depends_on:
      - db
      - webpacker
      - frontend
    environment:
      DB_PASSWORD: root
      DB_HOST: db
      WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST: webpacker # overwrites the webpacker.yml -> dev_server -> hosts value

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.4.10
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

  webpacker:
    build: ./backend
    command: ["/app/bin/webpack-dev-server"]
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    ports:
      - "3035:3035"

  frontend: //This one works fine
    build: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - ./frontend/node_modules:/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - '4200:4200'
```

**webpacker.yml:**

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/webpacker
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: false

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: false

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: 0.0.0.0
    port: 3035
    public: 0.0.0.0:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

**Console output on "docker-compose up" (build works fine):**

```
Creating network "lms_default" with the default driver
Creating lms_db_1        ... done
Creating lms_webpacker_1 ... done
Creating lms_frontend_1  ... done
Creating lms_backend_1   ... done
Attaching to lms_db_1, lms_frontend_1, lms_webpacker_1, lms_backend_1
frontend_1   | Your global Angular CLI version (8.3.23) is greater than your local
frontend_1   | version (8.1.3). The local Angular CLI version is used.
frontend_1   | 
frontend_1   | To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:25+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.4.10+maria~bionic started.
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:26+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:26+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.4.10+maria~bionic started.
backend_1    | wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for db:3306
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:26 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.4.10-MariaDB-1:10.4.10+maria~bionic) starting as process 1 ...
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:26 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
webpacker_1  | yarn run v1.21.1
webpacker_1  | error Command "webpack-dev-server" not found.
webpacker_1  | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
lms_webpacker_1 exited with code 1
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.10 started; log sequence number 20282472; transaction id 14616
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:28 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:28 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200128 12:11:28
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:28 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@c8d38e939209' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:28 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:28 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:28 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1         | Version: '10.4.10-MariaDB-1:10.4.10+maria~bionic'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
db_1         | 2020-01-28 12:11:29 8 [Warning] Aborted connection 8 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '192.168.0.5' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
backend_1    | wait-for-it.sh: db:3306 is available after 3 seconds
backend_1    | wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for webpacker:3035
frontend_1   | WARNING: This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications
frontend_1   | locally. It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.
frontend_1   | 
frontend_1   | Binding this server to an open connection can result in compromising your application or
frontend_1   | computer. Using a different host than the one passed to the "--host" flag might result in
frontend_1   | websocket connection issues. You might need to use "--disableHostCheck" if that's the
frontend_1   | case.
frontend_1   | ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://0.0.0.0:4200/webpack-dev-server/
frontend_1   | ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
frontend_1   | ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html
backend_1    | wait-for-it.sh: timeout occurred after waiting 15 seconds for webpacker:3035
frontend_1   | 
frontend_1   | chunk {0} 0.js, 0.js.map () 13.2 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {1} 1.js, 1.js.map () 19.9 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {2} 2.js, 2.js.map () 17 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {3} 3.js, 3.js.map () 31 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {4} 4.js, 4.js.map () 31.1 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {5} 5.js, 5.js.map () 57.5 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {6} 6.js, 6.js.map () 56.2 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {7} 7.js, 7.js.map () 4.59 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {8} 8.js, 8.js.map () 4.64 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {9} 9.js, 9.js.map () 9.43 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {10} 10.js, 10.js.map () 9.97 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {11} 11.js, 11.js.map () 3.71 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {12} 12.js, 12.js.map () 3.7 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {13} 13.js, 13.js.map () 22.7 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {14} 14.js, 14.js.map () 22.8 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {15} 15.js, 15.js.map () 12 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {16} 16.js, 16.js.map () 11.6 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {17} 17.js, 17.js.map () 8.39 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {18} 18.js, 18.js.map () 8.52 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {19} 19.js, 19.js.map () 5.61 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {20} 20.js, 20.js.map () 5.61 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {21} 21.js, 21.js.map () 15.9 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {22} 22.js, 22.js.map () 66.2 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {23} 23.js, 23.js.map () 65.9 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {24} 24.js, 24.js.map () 19 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {25} 25.js, 25.js.map () 18.1 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {26} 26.js, 26.js.map () 3.42 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {27} 27.js, 27.js.map () 12.6 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {28} 28.js, 28.js.map () 12.6 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {29} 29.js, 29.js.map () 14.4 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {30} 30.js, 30.js.map () 14.3 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {31} 31.js, 31.js.map () 25.7 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {32} 32.js, 32.js.map () 25.6 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {33} 33.js, 33.js.map () 39.2 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {34} 34.js, 34.js.map () 42.8 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {35} 35.js, 35.js.map () 13.1 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {36} 36.js, 36.js.map () 12.8 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {37} 37.js, 37.js.map () 31.6 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {38} 38.js, 38.js.map () 31.7 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {39} 39.js, 39.js.map () 14.9 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {40} 40.js, 40.js.map () 14.9 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {41} 41.js, 41.js.map () 37.5 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {42} 42.js, 42.js.map () 20.5 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {43} 43.js, 43.js.map () 19.8 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {44} 44.js, 44.js.map () 12.6 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {45} 45.js, 45.js.map () 12.6 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {46} 46.js, 46.js.map () 12 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {47} 47.js, 47.js.map () 12.2 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {48} 48.js, 48.js.map () 20.5 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {49} 49.js, 49.js.map () 21.9 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {50} 50.js, 50.js.map () 18.3 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {51} 51.js, 51.js.map () 18.3 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {52} 52.js, 52.js.map () 12.6 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {53} 53.js, 53.js.map () 12.6 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {54} 54.js, 54.js.map () 6.48 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {55} 55.js, 55.js.map () 24.4 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {56} 56.js, 56.js.map () 26.2 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {57} 57.js, 57.js.map () 23.9 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {58} 58.js, 58.js.map () 15.4 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {59} 59.js, 59.js.map () 15.1 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {60} 60.js, 60.js.map () 21.9 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {61} 61.js, 61.js.map () 21.9 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {62} 62.js, 62.js.map () 36.8 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {63} 63.js, 63.js.map () 36.8 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {64} 64.js, 64.js.map () 10.7 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {65} 65.js, 65.js.map () 6.5 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {66} 66.js, 66.js.map () 6.49 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {67} 67.js, 67.js.map () 14.2 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {68} 68.js, 68.js.map () 14.4 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {69} 69.js, 69.js.map () 8.34 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {70} 70.js, 70.js.map () 1.84 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {71} 71.js, 71.js.map () 12.4 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {72} 72.js, 72.js.map () 12.4 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {73} 73.js, 73.js.map () 18.1 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {74} 74.js, 74.js.map () 18.7 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {75} 75.js, 75.js.map () 11 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {76} 76.js, 76.js.map () 10.9 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {77} 77.js, 77.js.map () 20.2 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {common} common.js, common.js.map (common) 30.6 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {core-js-js} core-js-js.js, core-js-js.js.map (core-js-js) 78.7 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {css-shim-206ea950-3169f23e-js} css-shim-206ea950-3169f23e-js.js, css-shim-206ea950-3169f23e-js.js.map (css-shim-206ea950-3169f23e-js) 21.9 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {dom-96781eef-a2fb04dd-js} dom-96781eef-a2fb04dd-js.js, dom-96781eef-a2fb04dd-js.js.map (dom-96781eef-a2fb04dd-js) 19.8 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {dom-js} dom-js.js, dom-js.js.map (dom-js) 20.2 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {focus-visible-70713a0c-js} focus-visible-70713a0c-js.js, focus-visible-70713a0c-js.js.map (focus-visible-70713a0c-js) 2.15 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {hardware-back-button-5afe3cb0-js} hardware-back-button-5afe3cb0-js.js, hardware-back-button-5afe3cb0-js.js.map (hardware-back-button-5afe3cb0-js) 2.06 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {home-home-module} home-home-module.js, home-home-module.js.map (home-home-module) 34.4 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {index-69c37885-js} index-69c37885-js.js, index-69c37885-js.js.map (index-69c37885-js) 37.7 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {input-shims-7a8a317c-js} input-shims-7a8a317c-js.js, input-shims-7a8a317c-js.js.map (input-shims-7a8a317c-js) 13.5 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {ios-transition-becf5388-js} ios-transition-becf5388-js.js, ios-transition-becf5388-js.js.map (ios-transition-becf5388-js) 24.7 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {leaderboard-leaderboard-module} leaderboard-leaderboard-module.js, leaderboard-leaderboard-module.js.map (leaderboard-leaderboard-module) 20.8 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {login-login-module} login-login-module.js, login-login-module.js.map (login-login-module) 5.73 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 40.9 kB [initial] [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {md-transition-f444ed6d-js} md-transition-f444ed6d-js.js, md-transition-f444ed6d-js.js.map (md-transition-f444ed6d-js) 3.46 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 278 kB [initial] [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {profile-profile-module} profile-profile-module.js, profile-profile-module.js.map (profile-profile-module) 19.8 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {quiz-quiz-module} quiz-quiz-module.js, quiz-quiz-module.js.map (quiz-quiz-module) 22.5 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {quiz-result-quiz-result-module} quiz-result-quiz-result-module.js, quiz-result-quiz-result-module.js.map (quiz-result-quiz-result-module) 21.2 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 10 kB [entry] [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {shadow-css-4889ae62-23996f3f-js} shadow-css-4889ae62-23996f3f-js.js, shadow-css-4889ae62-23996f3f-js.js.map (shadow-css-4889ae62-23996f3f-js) 14.8 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {status-tap-7ab22cb8-js} status-tap-7ab22cb8-js.js, status-tap-7ab22cb8-js.js.map (status-tap-7ab22cb8-js) 1.79 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 112 kB [initial] [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {swipe-back-35ad8e37-js} swipe-back-35ad8e37-js.js, swipe-back-35ad8e37-js.js.map (swipe-back-35ad8e37-js) 2.68 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {swiper-bundle-ccdaac54-js} swiper-bundle-ccdaac54-js.js, swiper-bundle-ccdaac54-js.js.map (swiper-bundle-ccdaac54-js) 176 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {tabs-tabs-module} tabs-tabs-module.js, tabs-tabs-module.js.map (tabs-tabs-module) 8.14 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {tap-click-1f9d539e-js} tap-click-1f9d539e-js.js, tap-click-1f9d539e-js.js.map (tap-click-1f9d539e-js) 6.37 kB  [rendered]
frontend_1   | chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 5.03 MB [initial] [rendered]
frontend_1   | Date: 2020-01-28T12:11:46.647Z - Hash: f5c10ec9500752dc7639 - Time: 15503ms
frontend_1   | ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on 0.0.0.0:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
frontend_1   | ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
backend_1    | Database 'swm_lms_development' already exists
backend_1    | Database 'swm_lms_test' already exists
backend_1    | => Booting Puma
backend_1    | => Rails 6.0.0 application starting in development 
backend_1    | => Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
backend_1    | Puma starting in single mode...
backend_1    | * Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.5.5-p157), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
backend_1    | * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
backend_1    | * Environment: development
backend_1    | * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
backend_1    | Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

[Here the browser output of the rails project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVDM8.png)

Unfortunately I could'nt find any solution for my problem so I hope that someone here can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have not worked on any project that had a front-end of angular or any other JS framework i.e. my primary focus is rails back-end but I think the command you are looking for is `./bin/webpack-dev-server` not `webpack-dev-server` i.e. you need the complete path or it won't run. I hope you get the point.

Comment: Read the starting lines of your `webpacker.yml`. The issue is being caused by something there (you have different configurations for development and production, if settings that worked on linux were using development and current deployment is production, then different configurations might be the issue). Good Luck